# Disable NULL in CASE WHEN condition

Tags: mysql

I tried to run the script below, and it will display NULL value. I only want to get data for ALBANIA without having NULL value.

```
SELECT [COUNTRY_CODE_NEW]
      ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING([COUNTRY_CODE_NEW], 6,2) = '16' THEN 'ALBANIA'
        END 'COUNTRY'
  FROM [dbo].[COUNTRY_NEW]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do:

```
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING([COUNTRY_CODE_NEW], 6,2) = '16' AND IS NOT NULL THEN 'ALBANIA'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check to ensure it's not null:

```
SELECT
    [COUNTRY_CODE_NEW],
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING([COUNTRY_CODE_NEW], 6,2) = '16' AND [COUNTRY_CODE_NEW] IS NOT NULL THEN 'ALBANIA'
    END 'COUNTRY'
FROM [dbo].[COUNTRY_NEW]
```